# Parent folder's 'Date Modified' more recent than it's children folders' 'Date Modified'

Tags: macos

How can a parent folder's `'Date Modified'` be more recent than it's children folder’s `'Date Modified'`?

My scenario:

- The parent folder only has children folders, no children files
- None of the children folders has been modified
- No other commands have been used by me to modify the information of the folder
- The only things being modified in this are files in the children folders

Comment: Various ways. E.g. an item was deleted from the parent folder. The `touch` command was used to directly update the parent folder's modification date. An item in the parent folder was renamed. Why do you find this surprising?

Comment: @KenThomases You're right, I'll clarify my situation in the post